# Turn off url rewrite indexing for disabled products

Tags: magento-1.9, php, catalog, indexing

How can I turn off Catalog URL Rewrites indexing for disabled products in magento 1.9?

Comment: Isn't it already so?

Comment: Nope it is not.

Answer (score 3):

Finally this helped me a lot and now indexer time is much better. [Click here](https://www.dnd.fr/2012/09/magento-patch-how-to-optimize-re-index-processing-time-for-url-rewrite/) for reference url.